# Open cart installation bug of curl extension

Tags: php, open-source, opencart, opencart2.x

In opencart curl extension not exist but i turned it on from php.ini but I am unable to install opencart because curl extension not found.

Comment: You did not post the image, please add it.

Comment: What is the point to write it in arabic ?

Comment: from which source you are creating the question ?

Comment: Please up vote it  don't down vote help poor people

Comment: This is a English language website. Questions must be written in English to be on-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

From your description it seems that you are missing the `php5-curl` library.

You can add it with the following command:

`sudo apt-get install php5-curl`